# How do I show all hidden files, with some exceptions, in Finder on OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, finder

I'd like to show all hidden files in Finder windows on OS X, but there are some exceptions where I'd like to keep the hidden folders hidden.

How I'm showing all hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
killall Finder
```

I like seeing hidden folders just about everywhere except the Desktop, where it looks strange with `$RECYCLE.BIN`, `.DS_Store`, and `Thumbs.db` on it.

Can I keep just those files hidden?

Comment: how's that @techraf

Comment: Now that the question is clear, the answer is: no, you can't show all with `AppleShowAllFiles YES` and hide some.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can't be done in the way you wish.

You can hide the entire desktop contents, but not individual files/folders *whilst all files are visible*. Unfortunately, even using the hidden flag won't hide when `AppleShowAllFiles` is `true`.

To hide the desktop contents entirely, use
`defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false && killall Finder`
Reverse that with `true`

To hide or show individual files [when `AppleShowAllFiles` is **not** `true`] you can use SetFile, which is part of the Developer Command Line Tools.

`sudo setfile -a v /Users/you/Desktop/foo.bar` make invisible
`sudo setfile -a V /Users/you/Desktop/foo.bar` make visible

You can install the command line tools without needing all of Xcode, using
`xcode-select --install`
This will pop up a dialog asking if you want Xcode or just the tools. The tools are only about 150MB & will install quite quickly. No reboot required.